# Como iterar un ArrayList que esta dentro de un Hashmap

Tags: java, android, android-studio

es una pregunta sencilla pero no se como resolverla, en mi aplicación tengo un hashmap con la siguiente estructura:

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Article>> mlistDataChild;
```

- Ejemplo: `("VINOS", [Rosado, Blanco, Tinto])`

Quería saber como iterar sobre el ArrayList que se encuentra dentro del hashmap para sacar cada valor del array individualmente.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Y cómo quieres acceder al ArrayList?

Comment: Con un bucle sencillo, voy a probar la respuesta que me ha dado Evgeni, un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo así debe servir:

```
for (String clave : mlistDataChild.keySet()) {

    ArrayList<Article> articulos = mlistDataChild.get(clave);

    for (Article articulo : articulos) {
        // valor individual
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha sido de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes realizarlo de una forma optima obteniendo los elementos del array (u arrays) dentro del Hashmap `mlistDataChild`, mediante `entry.getValue()` :

```
for(Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : mlistDataChild.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " +  entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

teniendo como salida:

```
VINOS: [Rosado, Blanco, Tinto]
```

O imprimiendo cada elemento contenido en el array de tu Hash `mlistDataChild`:

```
for(Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : mlistDataChild.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":");
      for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(s);
      }
}
```

teniendo como salida:

```
VINOS: 
Rosado
Blanco
Tinto
```

---

Otra forma no tan optima pero que es válida sería:

```
    for (String key : mlistDataChild.keySet()) {
         ArrayList<String> item = mlistDataChild.get(key);
          System.out.println(key+":");
          for (String s : item) {
            System.out.println(s);
          }
     }
```

teniendo como salida:

```
VINOS: 
Rosado
Blanco
Tinto
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, probare tambien esta solución para ver de que forma puedo optimizar mejor el código, un saludo.